# Can folder actions be inherited?

Tags: folder-action

If I set up folder actions on a folder, is there a way to ensure that those actions would be also there for all subfolders of that one?

In other words, if folder actions are set for ~/bar, is there a way to ensure that they are there also on ~/bar/foo as soon as I have created the folder?

I have checked whether the folder actions are transferred when I duplicate a folder, but that's not the case, and this makes me think I am out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the Folder action you will have to add all sub folder in folder action set up and

**chose the folder action for each**.